# How to add category and tags to artefact in mavenrepository

Tags: maven, maven-central, maven-repository

Does anyone could explain how to update these values in the Maven Repository repository for my artifact:

- Category
- Tags

[image: Maven Artefact description]

Comment: There is nothing what you can do cause the pom.xml format is fixed. The screen shot is of mvnrepository and not from Central repository...

Comment: So my question is exactly about that. How can it be done. Just like for `JUnit` artefact.

Comment: I would ask for mvnrepository ...

Comment: I already did. In case I find out solution myself, I write it here

Comment: Have you tried with the tags one the version control repository?

Comment: The github repository of `junit` has the tags `test-framework` and `junit`.

Comment: I correct myself - I think it takes the tags from the group id and artefact id.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible using the org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin. Unfortunately I do not use it and so cannot test this, but as describe here: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/staging-releases/configuring-your-project-for-deployment, it is possible to add arbitrary tags which "can be accessed via the REST interface". I believe that the correct tag key (like tag or category) may show up in the HTTP interface of mvnrepository and https://central.sonatype.dev/

> As part of the configuration section for the plugin you can define tags with arbitrary key and value names. For example, you could create a tag with key localUsername and a value of the current user picked up from the USER environment variable:

```
...
<configuration>
...
  <tags>
    <localUsername>${env.USER}</localUsername>
    <javaVersion>${java.version}</javaVersion>
  </tags>
...
```

> Once components are released these tags are transformed into attributes stored along the components in the release repository and can be accessed via the REST interface and, therefore, any plugin and user interface integration.